# Custom Post Type Archive - archive.php is present, but it is not being used

Tags: custom-post-type-archives, template-hierarchy, archive-template

I have a custom post type called `Treatment`.

From my understanding of WordPress, `archive.php` will always be used unless there is an `archive-{posttype}.php`.

For some reason the archive page is instead using `landing-page.php` (my front page template), and I can't seem to get it to use anything else. Even with `archive.php` and `archive-treatment.php` present.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

`has_archive` is set, and I'm definitely viewing the correct URL. If I set `has_archive` to `false` it becomes a 404 error.

Here is my `register_custom_post_type()` for Treatments:

```
function register_custom_post_type() {
    register_post_type( 'treatment', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name'               => _x( 'Treatments', 'post type general name', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'singular_name'      => _x( 'Treatment', 'post type singular name', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'menu_name'          => _x( 'Treatments', 'admin menu', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'name_admin_bar'     => _x( 'Treatment', 'add new on admin bar', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'add_new'            => _x( 'Add New', 'treatment', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'add_new_item'       => __( 'Add New Treatment', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'new_item'           => __( 'New Treatment', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'edit_item'          => __( 'Edit Treatment', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'view_item'          => __( 'View Treatment', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'all_items'          => __( 'All Treatments', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'search_items'       => __( 'Search Treatments', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'parent_item_colon'  => __( 'Parent Treatment:', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'not_found'          => __( 'No treatment found.', 'nsc-treatments' ),
            'not_found_in_trash' => __( 'No treatment found in Trash.', 'nsc-treatments' ),
        ),

        // Frontend
        'has_archive'        => 'cosmetics/treatments',
        'public'             => false,
        'publicly_queryable' => false,

        // Admin
        'capability_type' => 'post',
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-screenoptions',
        'menu_position' => 10,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'show_in_menu'  => true,
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'supports'      => array(
            'title',
            'author',
        ),
    ) );
```

I have also tried changing `has_archive => 'cosmetics/treatments'` to:

```
'has_archive'        => 'true',
'rewrite'            =>  array( 'slug' => 'cosmetics/treatments' ),
```

As I've seen in other answers relating to this topic.

The theme is based of Underscores with no changes to anything under the hood. Only added CSS, template parts and custom post types.

I have reset the permalinks after each change.

Any help is greatly appreciated, as I'm still rather new to Wordpress

Comment: i recreated your setup so far and it should work. can you show us your `$args` array for and the `register_post_type` part of your cod and the part where `landing-page.php` is called in your code (with context please)?

Comment: Are you in minimal environment ?

Comment: As it is, your question seems a support question. You must have some code in your web generating that behaviour, impossible to know where. Please, provide more information.

Comment: @iantsch I've updated the question with more detail. I do not directly call 'landing-page.php' in code, only select the template for my static front page using the Wordpress frontend

Comment: your `publicly_queryable` and `public` flags are set to `false`. if you don't make your post_type `publicly_queryable`  and `public` the front-end will ignore it. source: [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)

Comment: @iantsch Thanks, that seems to have sorted it. Serves me right for copying code without a full understanding of the flags in use!

Could you submit as an answer rather than comment, so I can mark it as answered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `register_post_type` function you set your `publicly_queryable` and `public` flags to `false`. If you don't make your `post_type` `publicly_queryable` and `public`, the front-end will simply ignore it.

Source: [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)